# Don't understand meaning of verb stem + ちぎれない

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'm playing a game and looking at an item description. But for the life of me I cannot find out what grammar concept is behind the bold portion of the description.

I know the verb being used is 噛む (to chew). But I don't know how we got to 噛みちぎれない.
It seems like its the verb stem 噛み plus negative ちぎれる. But I can't find anything on the verb stem + another verb

The item description is

> **噛みちぎれない**ほど　硬～いフランスパン。でも　困った事にとても美味しいのである。
>   *Something about not chewing* hard French bread. But its very delicious for the annoyance.

Comment: I'm almost sure it's 噛みちぎれない.

Comment: It most definitely is. Just double checked and I have been reading it wrong this whole time... Still not sure how ちぎれない works though

Comment: 噛みちぎる https://jisho.org/search/%E5%99%9B%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8B

Comment: Oh wow its complete word in the potential form. When I tried searching on Jisho it split the word between 噛み and ちぎれない. Thanks for the correct link!

Comment: `But I can't find anything on the verb stem + another verb.` How is that possible when compound verbs are **so common** in Japanese?